# Can a concept evaluation depend on where it is evaluated?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++-concepts, c++20

[[temp.concept]/5](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.concept#5.sentence-1) says:

> A concept is not instantiated ([temp.spec]).
>   [ Note: An id-expression that denotes a concept specialization is evaluated as an expression ([expr.prim.id]). [...]]

Does it mean that this rule bellow ([[temp.point]/8](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.res#temp.point-8.sentence-4)) does not apply?

> If two different points of instantiation give a template specialization different meanings according to the one-definition rule, the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

---

For example if this rule does not apply, this code bellow is well formed:

```
template<class T>
concept Complete = sizeof(T)==sizeof(T);

struct A;

constexpr inline bool b1 = Complete<A>; //Complete<A>==false;

struct A{};

constexpr inline bool b2 = Complete<A>; //Complete<A>==true;
```

<sub>This question is followed by this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53263299/5632316)</sub>

Comment: @bolov Or `template<class A>` :-P

Comment: Are you sure the concept definition is well-formed when applied for `b1`?

Comment: That concept is ill-formed upon definition [IIUC](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.nondep#1).

Comment: @Oliv - The paragraph I linked says nothing about instantiation, it's about template **definition** and name lookup. I'd be shocked if one can conjure non-dependent identifiers willy-nilly in a concept.

Comment: @Oliv - Yes, `sizeof(A)`. It was an entirely different question with that typo. But whatever, if it was "*obvious*".

Comment: clang compiles it ok, gcc has `b2 == false`: https://godbolt.org/z/51qhTx . But gcc uses the old `bool` syntax for concepts, so maybe it's not up to date with the latest draft

Comment: @bolov I think that in the TS, concepts were very different. They where instantiated like variables or functions. In the TS concepts are defined under [decl.spec]. In the c++20 standard, concepts are treated as template, closely to the way are treated alias template.

Comment: FYI - the answer to this used to be Yes, but now it is No.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Can a concept evaluation depend on where it is evaluated?

No.

It used to be the case that this was true (as my answer before this edit stated), but it turns out that this severely inhibits compiler throughput (since you cannot cache the result of a concept check) and the motivation for having it to begin with was pretty weak. This was a very late change, adopted as part of [P2104](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p2104r0.html) in the Prague 2020 meeting which adds the following sentence to [temp.constr.atomic]:

> If, at different points in the program, the satisfaction result is different for identical atomic constraints and template arguments, the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

As a result, this:

```
template<class T>
concept Complete = sizeof(T) == sizeof(T);

struct A;
static_assert(!Complete<A>);
struct A {};
static_assert(Complete<A>);
```

is ill-formed, NDR (practically speaking, `Complete<A>` will still be `false` after `A` becomes complete). In other words, we "memoize" concepts in the same way we "memoize" template instantiations.

Comment: Thanks! Could you have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53263299/in-which-access-control-context-are-evaluated-concepts) too?

Comment: Note that it’s ill-formed NDR to have a template whose instantiations might be different because of such changes between two of its (potential) points of instantiation.  (Mostly this affects function templates.)