# In which access control context are concepts evaluated?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++-concepts, c++20

<sub>This question is a follow up to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53260099/can-a-concept-evaluation-depend-on-where-it-is-evaluated)</sub>

[[temp.concept]/5](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.concept#5.sentence-1) says:

> A concept is not instantiated ([temp.spec]).
>   [ Note: An id-expression that denotes a concept specialization is evaluated as an expression ([expr.prim.id]). [...]]

So maybe an expression that name a concept specialization can have different value because of accessibility.

If it were the case, I wonder in which context would be evaluated the expression:

- The context of the concept definition;
- The context of the expression;
- The context of the expression recursively applied to concepts expression appearing in concepts definition?

For example, what could be the value for `A::b2` and `A::b2_rec`?

```
template<class T>
concept has_private = requires(){ &T::private_;};

template<class T>
concept has_private_rec = has_private<T>;

class B{
   int private_;
   friend class A;
   };

inline constexpr bool b1 = has_private<B>;//I expects false
inline constexpr bool b1_rec = has_private_rec<B>;//I expects false

class A{
   static constexpr bool b2 = has_private<B>; //?
   static constexpr bool b2_rec = has_private_rec<B>; //?
};
```

Note Clang experimental concepts and gcc concepts TS implementation produce compilation error for b1 and b1_rec, but b2 and b2_rec are true;

Comment: I'm going to guess/hope that `b2` is `false` but honestly I do not know.

Comment: I’m tempted to bounty this, but fear it might bring well-meaning but poor answers.

Comment: @Oliv: The wording in the standard has since changed to say "A concept is not instantiated ([temp.spec]). [ Note: A concept-id ([temp.names]) is evaluated as an expression. A concept cannot be explicitly instantiated ([temp.explicit]), explicitly specialized ([temp.expl.spec]), or partially specialized. — end note ]", which I think ultimately means that the location of the concept can affect its value (in this case, due to class access control)

Answer (score 2):

First, let's start with `requires` expressions. The [section on the behavior of a `requires` expression](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.prim.req) has nothing special to say about the access controls of its component expressions. Similarly, the section on access controls says nothing in particular about `requires` expressions. In particular, there is [[class.access]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/class.access#4), which says:

> Access control is applied uniformly to all names, whether the names are referred to from declarations or expressions.

Given this, it seems quite clear that `requires` expressions don't need special rules. If you use a `requires` expression in a context which has access to some name, then the `requires` expression has access to that name. Otherwise, it cannot access the name.

So what of `concept`s themselves? Well, that's simple. [[temp.concept]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.concept#3) tells us:

> A concept-definition shall appear at namespace scope.

`concept`s are therefore global definitions; they can't be members of a class. So they cannot have access due to being a class member. `friend` can only specify functions or classes, and `concept`s are neither. So a `concept` cannot have access due to being a friend.

`concept`s are evaluated using special logic, defined in [[temp.names]/8](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.names#8):

> A concept-id evaluates to true if the concept's normalized constraint-expression is satisfied ([temp.constr.constr]) by the specified template arguments and false otherwise.

There is nothing in the rules laid down in [[temp.constr.constr]](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.constr.constr) which gives such evaluation any special access controls.

Therefore, any `requires` expressions used as part of a `concept` declaration use the global context for determining whether they can access names. That is, they can only ever use `public` interfaces.

Comment: The current implementations (GCC and Clang) use the context where the concept is first checked (and not the global one): https://godbolt.org/z/KEazqMPq9. Reported the bug: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=104111