# C++ concepts see a function for my type, but don't see it for std::vector

Tags: c++, templates, stdvector, c++-concepts

I'm trying to implement something like Haskell Prelude in C++ with typeclasses like Functor, Monoid, and so on. So I've decided to use C++ Concepts to do the type checking, but I encountered a problem while trying to implement Semigroup concept.

The problem occurs when I try to declare a concept that uses some function that is declared and overloaded for needed types later in the code, but it's only relevant for some types like std::vector, but for my own types works well.

Full code:

```
template<class T>
struct S {
    // ...
};

template<class T>
concept Addable = requires(T a, T b) {
    { add(a, b) } -> T;
};

template<class T>
S<T> add(const S<T> & a, const S<T> & b) {
    // ...
    return {};
}

template<class T>
std::vector<T> add(const std::vector<T> & a, const std::vector<T> & b) {
    // ...
    return {};
}

int main() {
    std::cout << Addable<S<int>> << '\n';
    std::cout << Addable<std::vector<int>> << '\n';
}
```

I expect the output `1 1`, but the actual output is `1 0`.
So, it doesn't recognize std::vector as Addable regardless to a declared add(std::vector) overload, but it does recognize the S type as Addable.

**UPD:**
The problem disappears if I move the `add` function to go before the `Addable` concept. But it looks very unhandy and unclear that I have to implement all concepts that I include for types like `std::vector` before I include those concepts.

**UPD2:**
I use GCC 9.1.0.

Comment: My guess is, `Addable` finds `add` for `S` via argument-dependent lookup, but can't do the same for `vector` since the class and the function are in different namespaces. Does it work if you declare or define `add` before `Addable`?

Comment: [Reproduced here](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/fZpWSD).

Comment: @chris Just as I thought - once you move `Addable` down, so `add` is visible to ordinary lookup, the program prints `1 1`

Comment: Note that Clang will give you some more info on _why_ if you fail an overload resolution check [as seen here](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/FT7wf-).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Does that mean that if i have a `std::vector` from stl and some `Addable` concept from a third-party library, i won't be able to implement that concept for a `vector`? Or I can do it only by putting the `add` before I include the header with `Addable`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a defect in this experimental Clang concept implementation. [[temp.concept]/8](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.concept#5) says:

> A concept is not instantiated ([temp.spec]).

See also: [In which access control context are evaluated concepts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53263299/in-which-access-control-context-are-evaluated-concepts)

That means that name resolution as it is described in [[temp.res]](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.res) does not apply to an expression that is a concept definition. If concepts had to be instantiated, then the function `add` could not be find by unqualified name look-up. This is why Clang generates an error.

According to the standard, when a id-expression names a concept, the [normalized](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.constr.normal#1.4) constraint-expression is evaluated where appears the id-expression ([[expr.prim.id]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.id#4)).

Less formaly, the expression that is the definition of the concept is evaluated in the context of the expression that names the concept. So `Addable<vector<int>>` should be true, because in the context of this expression, `add` can be found by unqualified name look-up.

Comment: It's not clang-specific, gcc 9.1 results in the same.

Comment: @bipil Originaly concepts where kind of functions or variables. The paragraph I site is relatively new: it was added to the standard last year and it is not part of the concept TS.