# How many specializations of class template with not-type template argument must become friends?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, friend

In the following code, there is template `struct A` with not-type template argument, and `class B` declares `A<0>` as its friend. Then the member function `A<x>::has_access()` is used to check that  it has access to private `B::p()`:

```
template<auto>
struct A {
    static constexpr bool has_access();
};

class B {
    void p() {}
    friend struct A<0>;
};

template<auto x>
constexpr bool A<x>::has_access() {
    return requires(B b) { b.p(); };
}

// #1: accepted by all
static_assert( A<0>::has_access() );
// #2: accepted by Clang
static_assert( A<1>::has_access() );
// #3: accepted by Clang and MSVC
static_assert( A<char(0)>::has_access() );
```

The program acceptance diverges:

1. `A<0>::has_access()` is `true` in all compilers I tested.
2. `A<1>::has_access()` is `true` in Clang only.
3. `A<char(0)>::has_access()` is `true` in Clang and MSVC only.

Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/P5njvzGee

Which compiler is right here? How many specializations of `A` must become friends of `B` after `friend struct A<0>`?

Comment: I don't see how 2 and 3 could possibly be true. Note that if you actually call `p` in `has_access`, then all compilers agree that 2 and 3 violate the access restriction. Looks like bugs in the requires-expression implementation to me.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53263299